# Problems passing arguments into functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

Probably a small problem in my understanding here but I'm sure it's easy for anyone who knows.

So my understanding was that I can pass arguments into functions like I have below, however, I assumed based on the values I pass in that my return would be a 1, however, I just get an empty array. Can anyone elaborate on why this is the case?

Thanks

```
function CreateBoard() {
    let board = {

      empty: 0,
      player1: 1,
      player2: 2,
      state: [[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],

      isEmpty: function(row,col) {
        return this.state[row][col] === this.empty;
      }
    };
    isEmpty(0,0);
}
```

Comment: **1.** You are not returning anything so the return value will be `undefined` not an empty array.

Comment: isEmpty can't be invoked like that.

Comment: **2.** a standalone function `isEmpty` doesn't exist. You have to call the `board`'s `isEmpty` like this: `board.isEmpty(...)`.

Comment: Is empty cant be invoked like this because I have identified that the fucntion is linked to the same scope as the board function?

Comment: I'm just trying to return the value of the current state of the array and position. I know i can use [] and dot notation but I thought this would work.

Comment: so `return board.isEmpty(0,0);`, because `isEmpty` is a property of the `board` object

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to return your object (`board`) from the function. Your `board` has several properties where `isEmpty` is also property (kind of a method). So you have to have an instance of `board` to call `isEmpty` on it.

```js
function CreateBoard() {
    let board = {

      empty: 0,
      player1: 1,
      player2: 2,
      state: [[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],

      isEmpty: function(row,col) {
        return this.state[row][col] === this.empty;
      }
    };
    
    return board;
}

let b = CreateBoard();

console.log(b.isEmpty(0,0))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is so helpful and now this makes sense to me thanks!